# How do I exclude specific time periods from availability test?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I created a availability test within the application insights to test my app service. Works fine except there are failures pretty much every night between 1:00 and 3:00. I'm guessing this is due to MS doing maintenance during this time period. How do I exclude this time period from sending out a alert via Azure Monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I exclude this time period from sending out a alert via Azure Monitor?

You can achieve this by using Alert processing rules (Currently in preview).

Alert processing rules allow you to apply processing on **fired alerts**.
You can use alert processing rules to add [action groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) or remove (suppress) action groups from your fired alerts.

Many customers set up a planned maintenance time for their resources, either on a one-off basis or on a regular schedule.
Those customers may choose to stop receiving alert notifications for those resources during the maintenance window.

Other customers do not need to receive alert notifications at all outside of their business hours.

**Limitations**:

You could suppress alert notifications by disabling the alert rules themselves, but this approach has several limitations:

- You could disable the relevant alert rule at the beginning of the maintenance window.
- You may have many alert rules that cover the resource. Updating all of them is time consuming and error prone.

You can refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-action-rules?tabs=portal#configuring-an-alert-processing-rule) for Configuring an alert processing rule.